# How compile TypeScript with unexist method in class for TDD?

Tags: typescript, testing, chai

I try to test my code using tdd approach. Every time then i create test for unexist method i get an error, for example:  `TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: error TS2339: Property '_get_model' does not exist on type 'Controller'`. It's true, doesn't exist. But how i can do tdd if compiler refuses to work?

For tests i using only ts, ts-node, @types/mocha, @types/chai

Comment: That's TDD - a failure to compile is a failing test. Now implement the empty method and see how the failure changes.

Comment: it's gone. But i want to see failing test but not failing ts-compiler. instead red-color test error i see in console that compiler checked my files, didn't find method and gave error.

Comment: ...so what? Is that unclear feedback that your code still needs work?

Comment: It's clear) but it's differ from js tests. If you say that it's ok, i will continue working with that

Comment: Yes, it's bound to be different - you now have an extra layer of type checking prior to checking functionality, *that's the point of TypeScript*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks! )